# how to join two variables

Tags: lua

In my Lua code I need to do an operation that allows me to join two variables (an integer and a float) but without using the Adds (+) operator. How can I get this result?

```
local A = 12
local B = 0.2
local C = A ???? B
C = 12.2
```

Comment: `C=math.log(math.exp(A)*math.exp(B))`

Comment: Why the restriction on using `+`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by removing the decimal point from `B`, then concatenating `A` and `B` using `string.format()`, and finally converting the resulting string into a number with `tonumber()`:

```lua
local A = 12
local B = 0.2
local C = tonumber(string.format("%d.%d", A, B*10))

print(C) --> 12.2
```

---

**EDIT:**
If you have an arbitrary number of digits after the decimal point, you can use this function remove it:

```lua
function remove_decimal_point(n)
    while n % 1 ~= 0 do
        n = n * 10
    end
    return n
end
```

Then,

```lua
local A = 12
local B = 0.2
local C = tonumber(string.format("%d.%d", A, remove_decimal_point(B)))

print(C) --> 12.2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by sum "0.0" to the integer value to turn into float like the following example:

```
local A = 12 + 0.0
local B = 0.2
local C = A + B

print(C)
```

Comment: Jose Lora, as I said at the beginning, I cannot use the Adds (+) operator

Comment: I did not understand

Comment: I mean it doesn't have short operations like "A += 1" to increase the values, just the operators like the example

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question, now I see what you want